# Cannot get every line of file with pipes

Tags: c, file, pipe, child-process

I'm trying to read files and return lines matching a keyword with children processes and communicate these to the parent, order doesn't matter.

My first question is: Is it possible to use only 1 pipe or the first process to finish will close the pipe?

My second question is that I have created a pipe for each child and still the parent doesn't read all of them, just shows all lines matching a keyword in the first file and first line matching of second file and stops.(I have tried with only 2 files but that's not the issue)

Assume all file opens and closes work ok. I have a check for all file opens, pipe() and fork(). The rest is not checked.

My code is as below:

```
#include "commons.h"
//efmalloc is error-free malloc

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int numargs = argc-1;
    int fds[numargs][2];
    pid_t n;

    for (int i = 0; i < numargs; i++) 
        pipe(fds[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < argc-1;i++){
        n = fork();
        if(n==0){
            close(fds[i][0]);//closing the read end of the pipe for the children
            FILE * fs = fopen(argv[i+1],"r");
            //// SETTING UP THE PARAMETERS FOR READING ////
            char * outputdata = (char*) efmalloc(400*sizeof(char));
            *outputdata = '\0';
            char * line = NULL;
            size_t len = 0;
            int read = getline(&line, &len, fs);
            int currentline = 1;
            ////    END OF READINGS SETUP ////

            while (read >= 0) {
                if(strstr(line,"keyword") != NULL) {
                    strcat(outputdata,argv[i+1]);
                    strcat(outputdata,line);
                    strcat(outputdata,"\0");
                    //Write the data in the pipe in here
                    write(fds[i][1],outputdata,(strlen(outputdata)+1));
                    *outputdata = '\0';
                }
                read = getline(&line, &len, fs);
                currentline++;
                }
            free(outputdata);
            fclose(fs);
            close(fds[i][1]);   //now closing the write end of the pipe
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    /***** PARENT PROCESS *****/
    if(n!=0) {
        for (int index = 0; index < numargs; index++)
            close(fds[index][1]);
        char * readmsg = (char*)efmalloc(BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char));
        for(int j = 0; j < numargs; j++){
            int bytes = read(fds[j][0],readmsg,BUFFER_SIZE);
            while(bytes>0){
                readmsg[bytes] = 0;
                printf("%s\n", readmsg);
                bytes = read(fds[j][0],readmsg,BUFFER_SIZE);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < numargs;i++)
                wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Split your code into functions. This will make debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

I see several minor problems, and two huge ones:

- `getline()` and `read()` both return `ssize_t`, not `int`.  They are **not** the same.
- `strcat(outputdata,"\0");` does nothing.  If `outputdata` is already properly terminated, it's not needed, and if `outputdata` is not already properly terminated it's undefined behavior.
- You're not providing enough space for a `'\0'` terminator in `readmsg` - you can read up to `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes, but `readmsg[BUFFER_SIZE] = 0;` is outside the buffer allocated.  This is undefined behavior.
- You can't be sure all your data actually fits into `outputdata`.  You keep stuffing more and more there no matter how much can actually fit.  If you overrun `outputdata`, you're again in undefined behavior.

Comment: I was given that line of the file is at max 256 characters and name of the file is at max 64 characters and I allocate 400 so it's more than enough. And thanks I will correct them.